# 'There is an argument" vs "there is argument"

Tags: phrases, phrasing

Hi everyone I'd like guidance as to whether it is ok to say "there is argument that" versus "there is an argument that' - is the shorte still correct?

Also 'there is need to' versus 'there is a need to'

Is either acceptable?

Thank you

Comment: Would those answering this question please answer the question. It's about potentially omitting the article (making *argument* into a mass noun). It's not about the word *that.*

Comment: The English Language and Usage Stack Exchange is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.
If you are learning English, please consider whether your question might be better suited for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

The word ‘that’ is rarely used after ‘argument’. You could either say “There is an argument about ___” or “There is an argument supporting/against ____”.

For the second question, the correct expression would be “There is a need to”.

Answer (score -1):

There are very few instances where I can put "that" after "argument." Some examples are "Jerry presented an argument that bewildered me" and "The argument that penguins can actually fly despite mountains of research to the contrary was not received well by the science community." Most of the time "argument" is followed by "about," or a verb like, "The argument failed." You can use "there is argument about" in the same way you can say "there is disagreement about," or "...is controversy over," "...is silence among." You cannot say, " There is need to..," however. Articles are weird, huh? In Spanish, articles have to agree with nouns in gender so despite our selectively applied rules, at least English is easier on that front.